# ¿Como hacer consultas a un backup en mysql sin tener que levantar este?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una BD que tiene respaldos cada 24hr, en la cual un dato fue modificado  y necesito verificar cuando ocurrió el cambio y necesito estar levantando cada respaldo y hacerle la consulta para ver si en ese día sufrió la modificación o no y por eso busco la manera de poder hacerlo automatizado y quisiera saber:

**¿Existe alguna manera de hacer consultas a los respaldos para no tener que estar levantando cada respaldo mandarle la consulta, eliminar esa BD y hacer lo mismo con el siguiente respaldo?**

Comment: No existe tal proceso. Lo que podrías hacer, en su lugar, sería implementar un sistema de rastreo o auditoría, donde registres los cambios (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) hechos en tus tablas.

Comment: [Discusión entre Marcos Gallardo y Luiggi Mendoza sobre si esta pregunta es demasiado amplia](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51326/discussion-between-marcos-gallardo-and-luiggi-mendoza). @MarcosGallardo en el futuro no borres los comentarios con enlaces a la sala de chat

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que no se puede, ya que un .sql lo que en realidad tiene son queries, mysql lo que hace es leer y ejecutar cada una de ellas.

Lo único que podrías hacer es lo que tú mencionas, levantar el respaldo, hacer tus consultas, borrar la base de datos y resubir la base de datos actual.